# Get avatar from user_id

Tags: php, wordpress, get, userid, avatar

1 - I have two members witch settings are set to subscribers.

2 - I have made a page in wordpress with the code:

```
<img src="get_avatar" alt="Logano" onerror="this.src='./files/defaultHead.jpg'"><a>Get_name</a>
```

3. Now I want get the members avatar to that img and also the name to this page.

How do I do this, what do I have to do?

I've tried to find a answer but I only see this: `<?php echo get_avatar( $id1, $size, $default, $alt ); ?>`

Comment: Are you trying to get just one, or are you looping through?

Comment: @fundamonarobot I want to pic the avatars from many users and call them from their user_id to <img src='<?php echo get_avatar("2") ?>' alt=''> This not working yet though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to think about PHP and HTML as 2 different languages.

`<?php` says, "we can start writing php now..." *and then* - `?>` says "back to regular HTML"

so... `<img src='' alt=''>` is the html... and you want a dynamic PHP call in there... right?

then... `<img src='<?php *stuff* ?>' alt=''>`

`<?php echo get_avatar( $id1, $size, $default, $alt ); ?>`

`echo` mean... "print out" sorta.

the `$things` with dollar signs are just placeholders from the doc...

If you read the page, it tells you what each on is. You can leave out the ones you don't need.

you can use your user's ID's or email address I think...

`<img src='<?php echo get_avatar("4") ?>' alt=''>`

So, something like this should get you on your way.

Scratch that... echo get_avatar spits out an image tag for you...

wonder what happens without the echo though... ?

So, `<?php echo get_avatar("4") ?>`

For the page name... it's the same idea

the html would be `<h2>the title</h2>`

so... `<h2><?php echo get_the_title( $ID ); ?></h2>`

You can put the page's ID in there `"2"` or - if it's in the loop, leave the `()` empty and then it will know to grab the name of that page.

Person name would be something like this:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata

```
<?php $user_info = get_userdata(1);
      echo $user_info->first_name . "\n";
?>
```

(in this case though... those $ are global variables... not placeholders. Documentation is really confusing... isn't it? ha )

Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you, yes I understand what you writing I think :) I found on one of the users that they have the user_id=2 so now "out on the other page" i put this in the image <img src='<?php echo get_avatar("2") ?>' alt=''> But it fails to get the avatar.

Comment: `get_avatar()` returns an `img` tag .. so instead of doing `<img src='<?php echo get_avatar("2") ?>' alt=''>`, simply do `<?php echo get_avatar(2); ?>`

Comment: Ah ha... @kaloyan - I haven't written much WordPress PHP lately --- good catch!

Comment: @Kaloyan awesome, that worked on the img, thank you! Still can't get the first_name though. <?php echo get_the_title(2); ?> This Give me a title of a page I have. And <?php echo get_first_name(2); ?> give me a error. Any ideas?

Comment: I made it by adding:

  <?php 
  $user_id = 1;
  $key = 'first_name';
  $single = true;
  $user_first = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single ); 
  echo '<span>' . '' . $user_first . '</span>'; 
?>

Answer (score 0):

Now when I managed to fix this I hit another one directly. I use buddypress and extended fields. When I look at the tag it's field_2 but I can't call it with the code above?

Comment: @Kaloyan Do you know this?

Comment: Sorry, not quite following you here. It is probably a good idea to check the plugins' documentation and if that doesn't help start a new thread with more information about the issue. This one seems to already have an answer. :)